# Wrap text around a LibreOffice Publisher object

Tags: microsoft-publisher, libreoffice-draw

Using LibreOffice Draw 6.1 how do we wrap text around a grouped object?

These were originally Microsoft Publisher files and we don't want to use Microsoft Publisher.

[image: Wrap Text around Grouped Object]

Comment: Your diagram doesn't show wrapped text.

Comment: [Wrapping Text Around Objects - LibreOffice Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Wrapping_Text_Around_Objects)?